# Retrieving dropdown options out of a database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to create a dropdown filled with numbers. These numbers need to be retrieved from a database. The connection to the database and the supposed display code are as follows:

The Function to retrieve the options for the dropdown

```
    <?php
    function dropdown_menu() {

    global $wpdb;
    /* Query the database */
    $query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM LID ORDER BY LidID', 'LID', 'LidID');
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    /* Check for $results */
    if(!empty($results)) :

    /* Loop through the $results and add each as a dropdown option */
    global $options;
    $options = '';
    foreach($results as $result) :

    echo ("<option value=\"<?php echo $item->LidID ?>\"> <?php echo $item->LidID ?> </option>");

    endforeach;
    endif; 
    }
    ?>
```

The statement which includes the aforementioned function into a form:

```
    <tr class="form-field form-required">
                <th scope="row"><label for="LidID">Lid ID <span class="description">(verplicht)</span></label></th>
                <td><select name="LidID" id="LidID" value="<?php echo $item->LidID ?>" aria-required="true"> <?php dropdown_menu(); ?> </select></td>
            </tr>
```

The problem I'm having, is that it creates a dropdown list with the corresponding amount of records of "LidID" in the database, but they all show up blank. I've already been toying around with it, and I think I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it. I presume the problem lies within the echo-statement;

```
    echo ("<option value=\"<?php echo $item->LidID ?>\"> <?php echo $item->LidID ?> </option>");
```

when I remove the second LidID ?> and replace it with, for example, a 5, it shows a list of fives. For some reason it doesn't recognize the statement I wrote. I've tried to switch out both the $item->LidID in the echo statement into $result->LidID, but that doesn't seem to have any impact. Does anyone have the slightest idea of what is going wrong here?

Oh yeah, I don't know if it's relevent but it's a plug-in for wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, that is the issue. You are already in PHP when echoing, so you don't need to open more PHP tags. The other issues is `$item` doesn't exist. Another issue is you're not using `MySQLi` correctly, you only use prepare if you have a variable, you don't so don't use it. You also don't use `get_results` in that context. Try this:

```
function dropdown_menu($default) {
    global $wpdb;
    /* Query the database */
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM LID ORDER BY LidID, LID, LidID';
    $results = $wpdb->query($query);
    while ($item = $results->fetch_assoc()):
        echo '<option value="'.$item->LidID.'"'.($item->LidID == $default ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$item->LidID.'</option>';
    endwhile;
}
```

Then when calling the function

```
<td>
    <select name="LidID" id="LidID" aria-required="true"> <?php dropdown_menu($item->LidID); ?> </select>
</td>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to do the trick either, they still show up empty

Comment: haha, I see you just edited your post as I wanted to reply again. I replaced the $item with $result and now it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're whole function was screwed up. I've updated my answer to show what it should look like.

Comment: I noticed. However, it tells me there is an unexpected ',' on line 26, which is the line '$query = 'SELECT ... etc'. I tried to remove everything after 'ORDER BY lidID', but that messed up my complete form.

Comment: That's because you've got quotation marks around the columns. I've removed them from my answer.

Comment: got it. Another side-question, I tried to declare the 'default value' of the dropdown to be set to $item->LidID. This value doesn't have anything to do with the function you've rewritten for me, it's been transferred to this page via the URL. It doesn't seem to work however, as it sets the default value to 0 instead of the value I've given it. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: You can't use `value` with a `select` input. You have to set the `option` as `selected`. I've updated my answer to include this.

Comment: and everything works perfectly now. A lot of thanks dude. Thanks for all the patience as well, I'm still all new to php so I've probably made some pretty basic mistakes as well. Have a nice day :)